# Flex shape - label overlap

Tags: flash, apache-flex, graphics, flex4, overlapping

I am creating a guitar tab display application in Flex and I need to display labels on top of horizontal lines.

I am creating the horizontal lines using the following code:

```
var s:UIComponent=new UIComponent();
    for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {
        var y:Number=getStringY(i);
        with (s.graphics) {
            //beginFill(0xB7B7B7);
            moveTo(15, y);
            lineStyle(1, 0xB7B7B7);
            lineTo(this.width - 15, y);
            //endFill();
        }
    }
this.addChild(s);
```

And then adding labels using

```
var l:Label=new Label();
l.x=xPos;
l.y=yPos;
l.text=labelText;
this.addChild(l);
```

However, the result I get is this ([http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/stackoverflow.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/607/stackoverflow.png/))
Notice the lower 4 is overlapped by the line we drew earlier.
This is causing readability issues, anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks,
Pranav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
var s:UIComponent=new UIComponent();
    for(var i:int=0; i<6; i++) {
        var y:Number=getStringY(i);
        with (s.graphics) {
            //beginFill(0xB7B7B7);
            moveTo(15, y);
            lineStyle(1, 0xB7B7B7);
            lineTo(this.width - 15, y);
            //endFill();
        }
    }
this.addChildAt(s, 0);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it works!
Here's what was happening:

Adding of the shapes was in the creation_complete handler, and adding the labels was happening immediately after the component was constructed, so labels were being added BEFORE the lines and hence, lines overlapped labels.

Thanks :)